# How can you visually represent which threads lock on which objects in Java while debugging?

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse

Using the following textbook thread wait/notify example, is there a tool (Eclipse plugin?) that tracks *which thread* locks on *which object* while stepping through and debugging? A tool that visually displays the connections in some way would be ideal if possible.

```
public class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();
        synchronized (b) {      
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                total += i;
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ( Note, `wait` should be in a `while` loop. You might also want to try `java.util.conncurrent` (I mean the collections and stuff, not `java.util.concurrent.locks`). )

Comment: Also, as mentioned in an [answer to another question using this code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17965872/27011), wait/notify should not be used on `Thread` objects, as those methods are also used by `Thread` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse support this already. There is a symbol in the stack of the debug window where a synchronized is. If you enable "Show Monitors" then you can also see the object on which are locks. You can set it in the options of the debug view "Java | Show Monitors".