# understanding synchronized in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Why usually threading samples put so many code in synchronized block. According to my understanding in following case synchronized is used just for locking b for wait and notify:

Main class ThreadA :

```
class ThreadA {
      public static void main(String [] args) {
         ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
         b.start();

         synchronized(b) {
            try {
               System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");

              b.wait();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
           System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }
     }
  }
```

and class ThreadB:

```
class ThreadB extends Thread {   
     int total;     
     public void run() {
        synchronized(this) 
        {
           System.out.println();
           for(int i=0;i<100;i++) 
           {
               System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
              total += i;
           }
           notify();
        }
     }
  }
```

What will change if I put just `wait` and `notify` in `synchronized` block:

```
class ThreadA {
      public static void main(String [] args) {
         ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
         b.start();
            try {
               System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");

                synchronized(b) {   b.wait();}
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
           System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());


     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

> According to my understanding in following case synchronized is used just for locking b for wait and notify

Your understanding is wrong.

`synchronized` is also used for:

- Mutual exclusion, to ensure that only one thread executes code "guarded" by a particular monitor at a time
- Ensuring memory access across threads is correct (that one thread sees changes made by another thread)

> What will change if I put just wait and notify in synchronized block:

In this particular case, it will make a difference based on a race condition - in the original code, if the new `thread` starts executing *before* the synchronized block is reached in the original thread, it won't get as far as "Waiting for b to complete" until the second thread has finished... at which point it will block forever in `wait`.

Note that it's a *really bad idea* to wait on `Thread` monitors, as `wait/notify` is used internally by `Thread`.

In short, the example you've used is a bad one to start with in various ways - but synchronization *is* used for more than just `wait/notify`.

Comment: >Note that it's a really bad idea to wait on Thread monitors. But how I can deal in this particular case when I need wait for thread to finish job?

Comment: @user1501700: Use a different monitor instead of the `Thread`... or better yet, use `Thread.join()` as that's what it's there for. Personally I wouldn't extend `Thread` either - implement `Runnable` and pass an instance to the `Thread` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `total += i` is **not** an atomic operation in Java. So you have to sync also this construct.

You also have not to sync notify() and wait() because their locks are handled internally.

Comment: but in this particular case it is safe not to sync total +=i, because nobody will edit it and according code it will be read only after notify, when total will not be edited. I am wrong?

Comment: you mean I can write just 'b.wait();' instead of 'synchronized(b) {   b.wait();}'?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by @sk2212, the increment operation is not atomic, but there is an equivalent atomic operation provided in high-level [concurrency primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html).